# Objects are not vaild as a React child in a flatlist?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Normally, I am able to render an array of objects in a Flatlist but for some reason this time I cannot.  I am getting an error, "Invariant Violation: Objects are not valid as a React child..."  Does anyone know why this is happening?

```
<FlatList 
    data={allergins}
    keyExtractor={(allergin, index) => index}
    renderItem={({allergin}) => (
        this.renderAllergins(allergin)
    )}
/>
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: It's as it says on the box - you can't render objects as children. Stringify them or parse them out.

Comment: I don't know how I would parse them out here but it does not work if I Stringify the allergins array.  Then allergin is undefined.  I need to be able to render the objects as children so that each one gets passed down.  We pass in arrays of objects to other flatlists in our app so I'm having trouble trying to figure out why it's not working here...

Comment: `FlatList` is not the issue here, `<Text>{ allergins }</Text>` is - `allergins` is an array of objects. React can handle the array, but not the object children.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I said in my comments, `FlatList` is not the issue. The issue is `<Text>{ allergins }</Text>`.

You can either:

**Stringify `allergins` (inline)**

```
<Text>{ JSON.stringify(allergins) }</Text>
```

**Map out the array**

```
allergins.map(allergin => <Text>{ allergin.name }</Text>)
```

You cannot render an object (i.e. `{ name: "Soy", value: "Free From" }`) in React. Valid children are strings, numbers, booleans, other elements/components, and arrays (of these types).

Answer (score 0):

So, it seems you are trying to render an object inside a Text. It is only going to accept strings/numbers as children. So what you have to do is:
If you have a know object structure, which seems to be the case, `this.renderAllergins` should look something like:

```
renderAllergins = allergin => (
  <View>
    <Text>{allergin.name}</Text>
    <Text>{allergin.value}</Text>
  </View>
)
```

The other option is rendering every key in the object. You would do that similar to this:

```
renderAllergins = allergin => (
  <View>
    {Object.keys(allergin).forEach((key, value) => (
      <Text>{value}</Text>
    ))}
  </View>
)
```

Answer (score 0):

For me, the `toString` or `JSON.stringify()` did not work, as i needed to pass the object which contained images as well.
So i did very simple thing:
I put the `{item}` within `<View></View>` tag.

```
<FlatList 
    data={allergins}
    keyExtractor={(allergin, index) => index}
    renderItem={({allergin}) => (
        <View>this.renderAllergins(allergin)</View> .   //You can try it as well
    )}
/>
```